# Knockoutjs not updating UI in this case

Tags: knockout.js

I am relatively new to KO (started 2 days back) and was trying some simple examples. Currently, I am having problem with this piece of code.

```html
<div id="idChangeStyle">
    <span data-bind="style: { background: GetAge() < 18 ? 'red':'white'}">Enter Your Age:</span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: GetAge"></input>
</div>
```

```js
function ageViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.age = ko.observable(18);
    self.GetAge = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.age();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseInt(String(value).replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
            if (isNaN(value))
                self.age(18);
            else
                self.age(value);
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ageViewModel(), document.getElementById('idChangeStyle'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJZqj/

Basically the app take a single input (age). I am using writable computed observable to parse the input to INTEGER and after parsing if its NaN i am trying to set the age to its default value 
i.e. 18. Also I have a simple logic on html where i am changing the background of span to red if age is below 18.

In normal case it works fine, here is when i get into problem:-

```
Case 1:
Current Input: 18 (initial case) 
enter *4* then tab //works
enter *a* then tab //work (defaults to 18) 
enter *a* then tab //doesn't work

case 2:
current input: 18 
enter *a *then tab* //*doesn't work
```

I checked the code of knockout to see what happens in a case when following piece of code run:-

```
if(isNaN(value))
   self.age(18);
```

.. in the following line:-

```
// Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
if ((!observable['equalityComparer']) || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
```

both the `_latestValue` and `arguments[0]` has the same value (18) so it's doing nothing. 
Due to no change in age value now the viewmodel property and UI are out of sync.

Is this because I am doing it wrong ?

Comment: You should look into using the [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you enter in the same value for an observable, it doesn't consider it a change in value and doesn't notify subscribers.  If you entered the error state multiple times consecutively, `18` would have been the set age at first and set again, no change events occur.

With that said, to fix that, you have to notify the subscribers manually. You can simply do that by calling `valueHasMutated()` on the observable.

```
self.GetAge = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.age();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        value = parseInt(String(value).replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
        if (isNaN(value)) self.age(18);
        else self.age(value);
        self.age.valueHasMutated(); // notify subscribers
    }
});
```

Comment: yup.. this is what i was looking for. thanks a lot. :)
BTW I don't see this mentioned anywhere in knockoutjs.com (manual, doc, examples etc) but now noticed it in knockoutjs code.
 
Is studying the code only way to know/learn?

Comment: In this case, yes. Unfortunately there's still some functionality that isn't officially documented. Though I wouldn't say you have to really _study_ it, just take a look at the implementation if you come across something that doesn't seem right as you have already done here.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation, when i use **knockout 3.0.** But these triks don't help me, because now **knockout notify only when computed properties value changes**.

And i fix problem:
1) use only notify:always

```
function ageViewModel(data) {
    //notify will should be always, because age is a primitive type  
    this.age = ko.observable(data.age).extend({notify: "always"});
    this.GetAge = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            // notify will  should be always, because computed return values of a primitive type.
            return this.age();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseInt(String(value).replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                this.age(18);
            }
            else this.age(value);

        },
        owner: this
    }).extend({notify: "always"});

};
```

2)  use notify:always and knockout.mapping

```
function ageViewModel(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    //notify will should be always, because age is a primitive type  
    this.age = this.age.extend({notify: "always"});
    this.GetAge = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            // notify will  should be always, because computed return values of a primitive type.
            return this.age();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseInt(String(value).replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                this.age(18);
            }
            else this.age(value);

        },
        owner: this
    }).extend({notify: "always"});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get around this is to set age to 0 and then back to the default.

i.e., change to:

```
if(isNaN(value)) {
    self.age(0);
    self.age(18);
}
```

I don't know what knockout would consider to be the "right" way, but that's probably what I would do.

Comment: yup.. that does the trick.. but here we will be calling same method for two times just to pass this test:-
if ((!observable['equalityComparer']) || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) { 

I was just wondering if there are any better solutions than this.